# trying to figure out jquery syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I was looking at this code and had a few questions. I did some digging in a jquery fundamentals manual and on google but didn't find a straightforward answer.

this is the full code

```
function slideSwitch()
{
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');


    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
         .addClass('active')
         .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
             $active.removeClass('active last-active');
          });
}
```

The first thing that strikes me is that he makes an inline if statement w/o brackets, that's cool and I didn't know you could do that. However, is it something that follows good coding standards or does it not matter?

Also the next line where he declares var $next. I've never seen a variable with those kinds of conditions in it. I'm guessing that he's saying either input $active.next() and if the length is 0 than $active.next() is going to be the first img in the slide show. I'm not quite sure what the operands mean.

any insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first thing that strikes me is that he makes an inline if statement w/o brackets

I think you mean braces `{}`.

> that's cool and I didn't know you could do that. However, is it something that follows good coding standards or does it not matter?

It is generally considered to be poor code style. It is too easy to come along later to add some more code to an `if` branch and not realise that the brace-less syntax was used.

[JSLint](http://jslint.com/) will complain about that.

> Also the next line where he declares var $next. I've never seen a variable with those kinds of conditions in it.

That's a [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
return condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (condition) {
    return expr1;
} else {
    return expr2;
}
```

All of this is JavaScript. It has nothing to do with the jQuery library.

Comment: aren't the selectors using the jquery library?

Comment: @Brodie — You weren't asking about the selectors.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need a refresher in using conditional statements:

1. A standard if executes a statement when the condition is evaluated to true/nonzero. A statement can be just that - a statement, or several statements within brackets.
2. A [ternary conditional expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a) is used for assignment purposes. It takes a condition, evaluates it and if it evaluates to true/nonzero it returns the first expression after the ?. If not, it returns the expression after the :.

Using an if with just a single statement makes sense, although the statement is usually pushed to the next line and indented for readability.

Using the ternary if is ok, as long as it does not contain nested expressions that make readability a challenge.